# How to return two promises? and make the code wait till execution is completed?

Tags: typescript

Have a code like this

I am trying to get the function to return true if the user is current user but the problem the code execution doesn't wait and it completes even before this code is executed?

Should I use async and await?

How to make Typescript to wait to get value of resultSet here?

P.S : I am new to Typescript

```
        const resultSet=  WorkItemFormService.getService().then(
            function(ServiceWTest){               

                const b=ServiceWTest.getFieldValues([userField]).then(function(value)
                {
                    var a=false;
                    if(currentUser==actualUser)
                    {
                        a=true;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    return Promise.resolve(a);
                });  
            return Promise.resolve(b);
        });

        var actiona=resultSet.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have enough context in this question, and/or have some issues to clean up before this question is fully formed. E.g. where does `actualUser` come from, how did you intend to use the variable `value` in the inner function?

Addressing the question more generally as applied to the broad strokes here, async/await would be a good solution. I think, if I'm reading the intent right, you're looking for something more like this:

```
async function myFunction() {
  const ServiceWTest = await WorkItemFormService.getService();
  const actualUser = await ServiceWTest.getFieldValues([userField]);
  const isCurrentUser = currentUser === actualUser;
  // Here you probably want to call a callback that handles what happens once you've found out the answer to "is this the current user?"
  doSomethingWith(isCurrentUser);
}
```

In promises that would be something like

```
WorkItemFormService.getService().then(ServiceWTest => (
  ServiceWTest.getFieldValues([userField]).then(actualUser => (
    actualUser === currentUser
  )
)).then(isActualUser => {
  doSomethingWith(isActualUser)
}
```

Comment: Yes I use the value and get the current user and check it to see whether actual user matches

Comment: Never mind I was trying to use await to prevent execution of other Javascript code which is not possible..my bad!